# Cannot integrate with FirebaseAnalytics and flutter-unity-view-widget

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to integrate flutter-unity-view-widget and FirebaseAnalytics in Unity but built iOS application failure with the following error message

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/cmj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axwkfpqujhueongqokkumujmrnsc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/cmj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axwkfpqujhueongqokkumujmrnsc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/cmj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axwkfpqujhueongqokkumujmrnsc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport'
ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### The Reproduce Steps

1. setup the dummy Unity project
2. setup the flutter-unity-view-widget as the [README](https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget) mentioned
3. setup the firebase as the [official](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) mentioned

now I can `export IOS (Release)` in Unity without any error, but I get the error message when running `flutter build ios`. It also fails when opening XCode and building the UnityFramework.

##### Analysis

I found that FirebaseAnalytics with Unity can be built as the iOS app and the XCode shows it has 12 dependencies (including FirebaseAnalytics), but only has 8 dependencies when building FirebaseAnalytics + FUW

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my team members and finding the solution

- should switch to Xcode project on iOS Resolver Settings from Xcode workspace in Assets / External Dependency Manager / iOS Resolver / Settings